# Using PCA in tidyverse framework with grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, pca

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
```

I know that `tidyverse` can be used to performance PCA, here two examples:

Example 1:

```
iris_pca_v1 <- iris %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    pca = map(data, ~prcomp(.x %>% select(-Species), center = T, scale = T)),
    pca_aug = map2(pca, data, ~augment(.x, data = .y))
  )
```

Example 2:

```
iris_pca_v2 <- iris %>% 
  select(-Species) %>%
  prcomp(center = T, scale = T)
```

But I'd like to know if there is a way to use the same `tidyverse` framework to apply PCA in grouped data. Suppose that I need to have different PCs for each Specie.

**Note:** In my real case I'm working with 20 variables for 50 states over 10 years, I'd like to apply PCA to make an index for each state, compressing the 20 variables into for the 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what your are looking for. To achieve your desired result you could nest or group by `Species`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

iris_pca_v1 <- iris %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    pca = map(data, ~prcomp(.x %>% select(-Species), center = T, scale = T)),
    pca_aug = map2(pca, data, ~augment(.x, data = .y))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(pca_aug) %>% 
  select(-data, -pca)
#> Warning: `...` must not be empty for ungrouped data frames.
#> Did you want `data = everything()`?

iris_pca_v2 <- iris %>% 
  nest(data = -Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    pca = map(data, ~ prcomp(.x, center = T, scale = T)),
    pca_aug = map2(pca, data, ~augment(.x, data = .y))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(pca_aug) %>% 
  select(-data, -pca)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris_pca_v1, aes(.fittedPC1, .fittedPC2, color = "iris_pca_v1")) +
  geom_point(data = iris_pca_v2, aes(.fittedPC1, .fittedPC2, color = "iris_pca_grouped")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(iris_pca_v1 = "black", iris_pca_grouped = "red" )) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: lifesaver solution

Comment: \what is the difference between grouped vs the first PCA?